# MaaS: Use Cloud-Init to automatically customize deployment process

Tags: juju, maas, cloud-init, curtin

I'm trying to do the following for a week with no luck!
I'd like to create a MACVLAN during machine deployment process. I've already provided a code for this process using Cloud-Init syntax:

```
#cloud-config

write_files:
-   content: |
        #!/bin/bash

        sudo ip link add eth0 link enp0s3 type macvlan mode bridge
        sudo ifconfig eth0 up
    path: /tmp/macvlan.sh
    permissions: '777'
-   content: |
        [Unit]
        Description=macvlan setup service

        [Service]
        ExecStart=/etc/init.d/macvlan.sh

        [Install]
        WantedBy=multi-user.target
    path: /tmp/macvlan.service
    permissions: '777'

runcmd:
-   sudo mv /tmp/macvlan.sh /etc/init.d/macvlan.sh
-   sudo mv /tmp/macvlan.service /etc/systemd/system/macvlan.service
-   systemctl enable macvlan
-   systemctl start macvlan
```

*So now I'd like to know how to use this code **automatically** during **deployment process**?* I know there is a way to manually use the code as the following:

```
maas $PROFILE machine deploy $SYSTEM_ID user_data=$(base64 ./import_key.sh)
```

But I want the MaaS to do it for all machines automatically (because I'm using Juju controller to deploy new machines and I can't do it manually).
If it is not possible to use Cloud-Init then is it possible to use Curtin? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer.
I added the following code to `/etc/maas/preseeds/curtin_userdata` file after `late_commands:` line ...

```
  foo_00: ["sh", "-c", "echo === Start Customization Scripts ==="]
  foo_02: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "sudo touch /etc/init.d/macvlan.sh"]
  foo_03: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "sudo touch /etc/systemd/system/macvlan.service"]
  foo_04: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "sudo chmod 777 /etc/init.d/macvlan.sh"]
  foo_05: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "sudo chmod 777 /etc/systemd/system/macvlan.service"]
  foo_06: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "sudo echo '#!/bin/bash' >> /etc/init.d/macvlan.sh"]
  foo_07: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "sudo echo ' ' >> /etc/init.d/macvlan.sh"]
  foo_08: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "sudo echo 'sudo ip link add eth0 link eno1 type macvlan mode bridge' >> /etc/init.d/macvlan.sh"]
  foo_09: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "sudo echo 'sudo ifconfig eth0 up' >> /etc/init.d/macvlan.sh"]
  foo_10: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "sudo echo '[Unit]' >> /etc/systemd/system/macvlan.service"]
  foo_11: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "sudo echo 'Description=macvlan setup service' >> /etc/systemd/system/macvlan.service"]
  foo_12: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "sudo echo ' ' >> /etc/systemd/system/macvlan.service"]
  foo_13: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "sudo echo '[Service]' >> /etc/systemd/system/macvlan.service"]
  foo_14: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "sudo echo 'ExecStart=/etc/init.d/macvlan.sh' >> /etc/systemd/system/macvlan.service"]
  foo_15: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "sudo echo ' ' >> /etc/systemd/system/macvlan.service"]
  foo_16: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "sudo echo '[Install]' >> /etc/systemd/system/macvlan.service"]
  foo_17: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "sudo echo 'WantedBy=multi-user.target' >> /etc/systemd/system/macvlan.service"]
  foo_18: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "sudo systemctl enable macvlan"]
  foo_19: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "sudo systemctl start macvlan"]
  foo_20: ["sh", "-c", "echo === Done Customization Scripts ==="]
```

Thanks all.